# Invalid public key inputs | Solana

Tags: python, solana

I'm trying to buy/sell solana coins using python. Here'a the function to perform buy.

```
program_id = '9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin'

def perform_buy(keypair,program_id,cli):
    account = Account(keypair[:32])
    new_account = Account()
    print(new_account.public_key())
    print(new_account.keypair())
    transaction = Transaction()
    transaction.add(sp.create_account(sp.CreateAccountParams(
        from_pubkey=keypair.public_key,
        new_account_pubkey=new_account.public_key(),
        lamports=10000,
        space=88,
        program_id=PublicKey(program_id),
    )))
    send_tx = cli.send_transaction(transaction, new_account)
    print(send_tx)
```

keypair is the wallets keypair.
I get the following error.

```
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/solana/publickey.py", line 33, in __init__
    raise ValueError("invalid public key input:", value) from err
ValueError: ('invalid public key input:', '<solana.account.Account object at 0x7f118669deb0>')
```

I have enough balance in my wallet(Sol coins).
What's this error about? How can I solve this?

Comment: `sp.CreateAccountParams()` fails I guess? What are the params that is expected for this method?

Comment: From the official docs. 
`    from_pubkey: PublicKey
    """"""
    new_account_pubkey: PublicKey
    """"""
    lamports: int
    """"""
    space: int
    """"""
    program_id: `

Comment: `from_pubkey=keypair.public_key` and       `new_account_pubkey=new_account.public_key()` give the public key right? 
`keypair.public_key()` is missing the invocation?

Comment: The `keypair` for `from_pubkey` is derived using Keypair hence public key is accessed using variable.public_key. And for `new_account_pubkey` since an Account is created, in this case we have to use variable.public_key()

Comment: Official Documentation: https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/